# URLFetch Problem with the Size of HTTP Message Body

Tags: web-access, internet

I am trying to transmit [this string](http://1drv.ms/1VmFRAW) as an HTTP Message BODY

```
url = "http://localhost:2480/batch/FILMSDB";

scrOK=Import["scrOK.m","Package"];

StringLength[scrOK]
1015

URLFetch[url, "StatusCode", "Method" -> "POST", "BodyData" -> scrOK]
200
```

scrOK is a batch SQL script that is executed successfully (200) on the OrientDB server

Now I am POSTing [a different string](http://1drv.ms/1Dr5166), i.e. batch SQL script.

```
scrFail=Import["scrFail.m","Package"];

StringLength[scrFail]
1156

URLFetch[url, "StatusCode", "Method" -> "POST", "BodyData" -> scrFail]
$Failed
```

and I am getting the message

URLFetch::invhttp: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data). >>

It is clear that the problem has to do with the Content-Length limit on the server that has been set to 1024 characters. I tried to modify headers but it fails.

```
URLFetch["http://localhost:2480", "Headers" -> {"Content-Length" -> 1000}]
```

The value {Content-Length ->2000} specified for the option Headers  \
is invalid.

```
URLFetch["http://localhost:2480", "Headers"][[7]]
{"Content-Length", "1350"}

URLFetch[url, "StatusCode", "Method" -> "POST", "Headers" -> {"Content-Length" -> 1200}, "BodyData" -> scrFail]
$Failed
```

What is really strange is that I have made the same tests on Google Chrome Postman App. The scrFail is passed and executed successfully. I am copying the curl code snippet

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 3f9ab406-1013-4bb1-f07a-c53ef6cc09eb" -d
```

and then the body (scrFail) follows.....

I cannot draw a final conclusion whether this is a problem with OrientDB or there is a way in Wolfram Language to overcome the Content-Length limit of the server. What do you think, please help.

PS: Someone with higher reputation score should change the tag of the question to urlfetch

Comment: The content length should reflect the actual length of the body data. If your server has a hard limit of 1024 bytes, then it is expected to fail when sending more content, even if the content length header says something else. Did your test with curl was against the same server?

Comment: If I try to set the content length of the body data with an option such as "Headers" -> {"Content-Length" -> 1156} I am getting an error message of the type General::erropts: The value {Content-Length->1156} specified for the option Headers is invalid.

Comment: I tested successfully scrFail body with Google Chrome Postman against the same server. Postman has an option to generate code snippet in Curl.

Comment: What happens if you specify the header as a string: `"Headers" -> {"Content-Length" -> "1200"}`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem is only reproducible in a specific version of OrientDB, which makes it only vaguely related to Mathematica.

Comment: I am leaving it up to you, although I would not like a reduction on my reputation score

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved in OrientDB community version 2.1
I have tried the POST method with string content of size over 10kB
It works, so no need to set the content length.